# Storing inputted strings in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

How do I store the inputted strings into an array?

I hope someone would give me tips on how to store inputs in an array..

I'd like to store items in an array.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()  {

    cout << "MANG JUAN'S 10-DAHAN\n\n";
    cout << "A - BALOT = 25.00\tD - KETCHUP = 50.00\tG - VINEGAR = 25.00\n";
    cout << "B - CANTON = 20.00\tE - MAGGI = 15.00\tH - OIL = 70.00\n";   
    cout << "C - NIDO = 100.00\tF - ALASKA = 60.00\tI - COKE = 10.00\n";
    cout << "\nWOULD YOU LIKE TO PURCHASE? Y/N\n\n";

    int quantity;
    char item, addAnother, choice;
    double price, total, grandTotal;

    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 'n' || choice == 'N') {
             cout << "\n\nThank you.\n\n";
    } else if (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y') {
           string numPref;
           int i = 1;
           while ( i <= 10 ) {
               switch(i) { 
                         case 1: numPref = "st";
                                 break;
                         case 2: numPref = "nd";
                                 break;
                         case 3: numPref = "rd";
                                 break;
                         case 4:
                         case 5:
                         case 6:
                         case 7:
                         case 8:
                         case 9:
                         case 10: numPref = "th";
                                  break;
                         default: cout << "\n\nTHE SYSTEM EXCEEDED ITS LIMIT\n\n";
               }
               cout << "\n\nPLEASE ENTER " << i << numPref << " ITEM:\t";
               cin >> item;
               if( !cin ) {
                   cout << "ENTER A - H ONLY..";
               } else {
               cout << "HOW MANY?\t";
               cin >> quantity;

               switch(item) {
                        case 'a':
                        case 'A':
                        case 'g':
                        case 'G':
                             price = 25.00;
                             break;
                        case 'b':
                        case 'B':
                             price = 20.00;
                             break;
                        case 'c':
                        case 'C':
                             price = 100.00;
                             break;
                        case 'd':
                        case 'D':
                             price = 50.00;
                             break;
                        case 'e':
                        case 'E':
                             price = 15.00;
                             break;
                        case 'f':
                        case 'F':
                             price = 60.00;
                             break;
                        case 'h':
                        case 'H':
                             price = 70.00;
                             break;
                        case 'i':
                        case 'I':
                             price = 10.00;
                             break;
               }
               cout << "PRICE PER ITEM\t" << price << endl;
               total = quantity * price;
               cout << "TOTAL\t\t" << total << "\n\n";
               grandTotal += total;

               cout << "ADD ANOTHER ITEM? Y/N" << endl;
               cin >> addAnother;
                   if ( addAnother == 'n' || addAnother == 'N' ) {
                      cout << "\n\nPLEASE PAY: " << grandTotal;
                      cout << "\n\n";
                      break;
                   } else if ( addAnother == 'y' || addAnother == 'Y' ) {
                      cout << i++;
                   } else { cout << "INVALID INPUT.."; break;}
                   }
           }
    } else {
           cout << "INVALID INPUT..\n\n";
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm reviewing myself in C++, unfortunately I forgot how to store arrays..

Comment: *"ENTER A - H ONLY.."* - Switch has A - I

Comment: Take a look at std::vector, it can be used as an array, and it can easilty be sorted by using std::sort(...) http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: Those are not strings, those are *characters*.